# Abstract algebra,polynomial rings

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory

I recently took my first abstract algebra class and I'm loving it, so here I am asking for some help studying

The professor mentioned how in polynomial rings, if $x$ is the ordered sequence $(0,1,0,0,...)$, then $x^2$ is $(0,0,1,0,...)$ etc. Although I get why that is, I can find no book mentioning it. Can you recommend any book or resource online with a really detailed, theoretical approach to rings, that requires no background in abstract algebra?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This approach to define polynomials using sequences which are zero almost everywhere are quite common. It is also mentioned in the fabulous beginner's book "Algebra" by Michael Artin. Thomas Hungerford ("Algebra") defines the polynomial ring exactly with those sequences and then develops the "ordinary" (well known) representation of polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely find the claim that $k[x]$ is a $k$-vector space, and basic linear algebra is the only thing needed to understand this situation.

There is a particularly natural basis for $k[x]$: $\{1, x, x^2, x^3,\ldots\}$. Using this basis, you have the obvious isomorphism $k[x]\cong \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty k$.

The coordinates with respect to this ordered basis are precisely the sequences you mention.

Comment: Thanks for the response.It was pretty helpful

I'd like to make another question that bothers me is what's the reason for polynomial functions.I get polynomials as an extension of a ring,but why would one wet another function from R[x]->R?(Although the definition says that it's from R->R).This topic really confuses me

Comment: @FotisRokanis for each $r\in R$, you can assign f(r)\in R$. This defines a function, but I wouldn’t say the polynomial *is* a function.